# login method is not calling using databinding in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

Hi I have this `layout` and I am trying to call login `viewmodel` function from the `layout` on click on `button` but it is not calling.

Does anyone know whats issue ? How to resolve it ?

**activity_login.xml**

```
<layout>

    <data>

        <variable
            name="loginViewModel"
            type="com.app.android.login.LoginViewModel" />
    </data>

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        tools:context="com.app.android.login.LoginActivity"
        tools:ignore="missingPrefix">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/default_view_margin_bottom_8dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_login_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_view_margin_right_8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_view_margin_left_8dp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorSecondaryText"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.InputLayoutStyle"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/til_login_password"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/login_email"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@={loginViewModel.email}"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_login_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_view_margin_right_8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_view_margin_left_8dp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorSecondaryText"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.InputLayoutStyle"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_login_login"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/til_login_email"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/login_password"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@={loginViewModel.password}"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_login_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_view_margin_right_8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_view_margin_left_8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                android:onClick="@{loginViewModel.login}"
                android:text="@string/login_btn_text"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textview_login_forgot_password"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/til_login_password"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_login_forgot_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_view_margin_right_8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_view_margin_left_8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/login_forgot_password"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_login_register"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_login_login"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_login_register"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_view_margin_right_8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_view_margin_left_8dp"
                android:text="@string/login_sign_up"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</layout>
```

**LoginActivity.kt**

```
class LoginActivity : BaseActivity(), LoginNavigator {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val activityLoginBinding: ActivityLoginBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityLoginBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_login)
    }

    override fun startHomeActivity() {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun startRegistrationActivity() {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun startForgotPasswordActivity() {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun handleError(throwable: Throwable) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

}
```

**LoginViewModel.kt**

```
class LoginViewModel : AnkoLogger {

    val email = ObservableField<String>()
    val password = ObservableField<String>()

    fun login(view: View) {
        val viewVisibility: Int = view.visibility
        info { viewVisibility }
        info {
            "${email} and ${password}"
        }
    }

    /**
     * Validate email and password. It checks email and password is empty or not
     * and validate email address is correct or not
     * @param email email address for login
     * @param password password for login
     * @return true if email and password pass all conditions else false
     */
    fun isEmailAndPasswordValid(email: String, password: String): Boolean {

        if (email.isEmpty()) return false

        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) return false

        if (password.isEmpty()) return false

        return true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a look at you `Activity`, it seems you're missing to set the `viewModel` variable there.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val activityLoginBinding: ActivityLoginBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityLoginBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_login)
    activityLoginBinding.loginViewModel = LoginViewModel()
}
```